# Nested Resources without ID of parent in the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

I have two resources:

```
resources :users do
 resources :cars
end
```

The association is:

- A user can have many cars
- A car belongs to a user

When doing that kind of nested resourcing, I get urls like:

```
/users/:id/cars/new
```

My question is:

If it makes more sense to do just `/cars/new` (without the /users/:id) because I get the `:id` from the current_user logged in, how would I solve that in the routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use nested routes at all.  You can have nested models without having to have nested routes.  Just load the current user from the session (you're probably doing this already), and make sure no one can access the cars controller unless they're logged in.

Comment: +1 and make sure you're only loading the car that belongs to current user :D

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer for this question is:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    resources :cars
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb

```
resources :cars, :only => [:new, :create] # if you don't need all actions
resources :users do
  resources :cars
end
```

In cars controller something like

```
before_filter :find_user
...
private
def find_user
  @user = params[:user_id] ? User.find(params[:user_id]) : current_user
end
```